# How to always check if the Location service is enabled in Ionic 2?

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2

I am trying to figure out how to always check if the location service is enabled. By always I mean like a real-time checker. What I have now is only in one view. I am checking when the user signs in - if the location service is enabled, he signs in. However, if it's unenabled then an Alert dialog appears:

This is my function that checks if it's enabled:

```
 checkLocation() {
    this.diagnostic.isLocationEnabled().then(
      (isAvailable) => {
        console.log('Is available? ' + isAvailable);
        if (isAvailable) {
          this.navCtrl.setRoot(UserTypePage);
        } else {
          alert('Please turn on the location service');
          if (this.autoLogin) {
            this.autoLogin();
          }
        }
      }).catch((e) => {
        console.log(e);
        alert(JSON.stringify(e));
      });
  }
```

I call this function when a user tries to sign in.

Example with Facebook sign in:

```
facebookLogin(): void {
    this.global = ShareService.getInstance();
    this.subscriptions.push(this.authProvider.loginWithFacebook().subscribe((user) => {
      this.loading.dismiss().then(() => {

        this.global.setUserName(user.displayName); 
        this.global.setProfilePicture(user.photoURL);
        this.global.setUserId(this.authProvider.currentUserId);
        this.tokenstore();
        this.checkLocation(); //HERE
      })

    }, error => {
      this.loading.dismiss().then(() => {
        let alert = this.alertCtrl.create({
          message: error.message,
          buttons: [
            {
              text: "Ok",
              role: 'cancel'
            }
          ]
        });
        alert.present();
      });
    }, (err) => {
      console.error("error: " + JSON.stringify(err));
    }));
    this.loading = this.loadingCtrl.create({
      content: 'Signing in...'
    });
    this.loading.present();
  }
```

I want this function to work in the whole application not just in the login view. How do I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a classic scenario where Angular Dependency Injection will help you to reuse an existing method across components/views.

You can create a LocationCommonService in your application and define the method to check if Location service is enabled.

Now inject LocationCommonService in all the components where there is a need to call the required function.